# How to auto deploy to Flynn using Travis CI?

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci

I tried to do as the instructions here: https://blog.evantahler.com/deploying-to-flynn-from-travis-ci-d28f73e3ac99 but it does not seem to work. I get this error:

server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

How do I solve it? Do I need to add a ssl cert that is not self signed?